# Discrepancy between layer digests obtained with `docker inspect` and those from the registry API

Tags: docker, docker-registry

`docker inspect --type image the_image` on a local image yields a list of SHA256 digests (`RootFS/Digests`) which isn't the same as the one I get from the same image in the registry (`ManifetsV2/Layers/*/Digest`).

- Docker is 18.03.1-ce
- Registry is "github.com/docker/distribution v2.6.2"

Is this discrepancy normal? If so is there a way to match layers in a local image with layers in a registry image without pulling the registry image?